# Парсинг с помощью Grab на Python

Tags: python, grab

Беру пример из документации (http://docs.grablib.org/ru/latest/grab/text_search.html#id2) и просто копирую его. Он не работает. Выдается ошибка

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grab/util/warning.py:28: GrabDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function search. Use grab.doc.text_search instead.
warn(message)
```

Весь код:

```
from grab import Grab 

g = Grab()
url = 'https://news.yandex.ru/index.rss'
g.go(url)

g.search(u'яндекс'.encode('utf-8'), byte=True)
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение: используйте `g.doc.text_search`. Второй момент - попробуйте искать "Яндекс" (с большой буквы). Третий момент - попробуйте распечатать то, что возвращает метод

Comment: Отлично по всем трем пунктам.
1. Если распечатывать то, что присылает ответ (код без правок), то ругается и возвращает фалс. 2. Если с большой буквы, то ругается и тру. 3. Если использовать g.doc.text_search, то все ок. Стыдно, что методом тыка не попытался подставить. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем `g.doc.text_search`

Код в итоге выглядит так:

```
from grab import Grab 

g = Grab()
url = 'https://news.yandex.ru/index.rss'
g.go(url)

print (g.doc.text_search(u'Яндекс'.encode('utf-8'), byte=True))
```

Спасибо пользователю @soon